# Use mapBox tile as osmdroid tileSource

Tags: android, mapbox, osmdroid

I am new on map in android and I want to create simple map application with `osmdroid`.
I added

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.3'
```

to my gradle and i use in this way in ma class:

```
final ITileSource tileSource = TileSourceFactory.HIKEBIKEMAP;
mapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
mapView.setTilesScaledToDpi(true);
mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Now i am using `TileSourceFactory.HIKEBIKEMAP` as a tile source. According this [page](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources) I want to use mapbox tile so in order i registered in [mapbox site](http://account.mapbox.com) and i created `Access tokens` now i can not find to create `MAPBOX_MAPID` where is it?

After create `ID` how can i use [mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important fact to note: The `mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8` is a **vector** tileset. Vector tiles are not directly supported by Osmdroid, only bitmap are. Fortunately, Mapbox is still provides bitmap tiles for their tilesets.

Use `mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8` ( you can also try `mapbox.streets` for example) as `MAPBOX_MAPID` and use `MapBoxTileSource` as described in the osmdroid documentation.

```
final MapBoxTileSource tileSource = new MapBoxTileSource();
//option 1, load your settings from the manifest
tileSource.retrieveAccessToken(context);
tileSource.retrieveMapBoxMapId(context);
//option 2, provide them programmatically
tileSource.setAccessToken(context);
tileSource.setMapBoxMapId(context);
mMapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapBox static tiles like that:

```
val tileSize = 256
val style = "streets-v11"
val tileSource = object : OnlineTileSourceBase(
    "MapBox", 5, 18, tileSize, ".png",
    arrayOf("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/$style/tiles/$tileSize")
) {
    override fun getTileURLString(tileIndex: Long): String {
        return baseUrl +
            "/${MapTileIndex.getZoom(tileIndex)}" +
            "/${MapTileIndex.getX(tileIndex)}" +
            "/${MapTileIndex.getY(tileIndex)}" +
            "?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN"
    }
}
mMapView.setTileSource(tileSource)
```

See [documentation](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/Map-Sources.html).
You can take style names from [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/).